# Update Select Box After Another Select Box Change

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this code here:

```
App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
selectedCabinet: null,
selectedTabs: null,

selectCabinetData: function() {
    return this.store.find('cabinets')
}.property('@each.cabinets') ,

actions: {
    searchFiles: null,
},
selectedCabinetChanged: function() {
    console.log(this.selectedCabinet.id)
    if (this.selectedCabinet){
        return this.store.find("tabs", {cabinet: this.selectedCabinet.id})
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}.observes('selectedCabinet')
});
```

I can see the ajax request and it filters, but it doesnt update the select box here

> {{view Ember.Select
>                   contentBinding=selectCabinetChanged
>                   selectionBinding="selectedTabs"
>                   optionValuePath="content.id"
>                   optionLabelPath="content.tab_name"
>                   prompt="Select A Tab"}}

Essentially based on the value of the first select box will dictate the results of the other.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Why you tagged Django?

Comment: Sorry, I left out I was using the django rest adapter for ember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.store.find("tabs", { ... })` returns a promise instead of the array, so you will need to create a `filteredTabs` property and set the value with the result from the resolved promise:

```
App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    selectedCabinet: null,
    selectedTabs: null,
    filteredTabs: null,
    selectCabinetData: function(){
        return this.store.find('cabinets')
    }.property('@each.cabinets'),
    actions: {
        searchFiles: null,
    },
    selectedCabinetChanged: function() {
        var controller = this;        
        if(this.get('selectedCabinet')){
            this.store.find("tabs", { cabinet: this.get("selectedCabinet.id") }).then(function(filteredTabs) {
                controller.set('filteredTabs', filteredTabs);
            });
        } else {
            controller.set('filteredTabs', null);
        }
    }.observes('selectedCabinet')
});
```

Update your `contentBinding=selectCabinetChanged` to `contentBinding=filteredTabs` like this:

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding=filteredTabs selectionBinding="selectedTabs" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.tab_name" prompt="Select A Tab"}}
```

Comment: I have made the changes as so:

App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    selectedCabinet: null,
    selectedTabs: null,
    
    selectCabinetData: function() {
        return this.store.find('cabinets')
    }.property('@each.cabinets') ,

    actions: {
        searchFiles: null,
    },
    selectedCabinetChanged: function() {
        console.log("Changed")
        if (this.selectedCabinet){
            return this.store.find("tabs", {cabinet: this.get("selectedCabinet.id")})
        }else{
            return null; 
        }
    }.property('selectedCabinet')
});

Comment: And now it doesnt catch the change of the first select box.

Comment: I updated the answer, that time you have the observer back, but now the contentBinding is equals to filteredTabs